# How to distinguish the Dropdown item event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drop-down-menu

I am working with Element.io with Vue.js.

[Dropdown Command Event](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/dropdown#command-event)

Using a Dropdown. I want to click a Dropdown Item it will fire a Method.

Dropdown Code:

```
<el-dropdown placement="left" @command="handleCommand">
    <img :src="vmenu" alt="Vertical Menu" width="20" style="margin-top: 6px;">
    <el-dropdown-menu slot="dropdown" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
         <el-dropdown-item icon="el-icon-edit-outline">Edit</el-dropdown-item>
         <el-dropdown-item icon="el-icon-circle-plus" command="a" v-show="scope.row.isPause===false">Pause</el-dropdown-item>
         <el-dropdown-item icon="el-icon-caret-right" command="b" v-show="scope.row.isPause===true">Enable</el-dropdown-item>
         <el-dropdown-item icon="el-icon-menu" command="c">Duplicate</el-dropdown-item>
         <el-dropdown-item icon="el-icon-delete" style="color: red;">Delete</el-dropdown-item>
    </el-dropdown-menu>
</el-dropdown>
```

Method:

```
methods: {
   handleCommand(command){
        if(command== (a)(command)){
            this.isPause = !this.isPause
            console.log(command);
        }
    }
}
```

While I am clicking on a Command then giving this error:

> Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: a is not defined"

Now my Question is:
While I will click "a" command, then, it will fire a Method like: "a" but giving error!!!!

Comment: `a`, `b` are methods defined like `methods:{a(){}, ...}`?

Comment: define a because you using in if command and in argument you only passing command. so either define a method and than use this.a or define argument or variable.

Comment: Will you please add some code what you are meaning? @MandeepGill

Comment: I think @MandeepGill means create a methof "a" for example `function a () {  /* ... */ }`  or inside `methods`, like `methods: {  /* ... */   a: function () {  /* ..... */  }  }`

Answer (score 1):

The value 'a' will be assigned to the variable `command` inside the `handleCommand` method. You should use the comparison `command === 'a'` inside the if statement.

Comment: Hi, that statement is not completely true, the `command` variable is an argument, its value is assigned before the method starts, not inside the method... Also if @aspile changes their code from `if(command== (a)(command)){` to `if(command === 'a'(command)){` it will still fail. A correct example would be `if(command === 'a'){`

Comment: You are right @gregn3. I tried with this before posting here. It will not work.

Comment: If you use `if(command === 'a'(command)){}`, `a` will be treated as a function name and in this case that function is undefined. I'm guessing the OP wants to do something when the `Pause` option is selected, if my guess is correct, you need use the comparison `command === 'a'` inside the if statement. Just as @gregn3 sugested.